# Remote access to private networks with overlapping IP address space on OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, ip

Good day,

I am currently trying to setup a system where we have a VPN connection to number of nodes with devices on their LAN having same IP address connecting to the server which is a big no-no and to get around this issue [OpenVPN suggests using the following method](https://openvpn.net/cloud-docs/remote-access-private-networks-overlapping-ip-address/).

Essentially, I am in a situation where I will have multiple nodes with the same setup scattered throughout different sites:

```
Client site Home
|RUT240 router (vpn connect)|<----------> |OpenVPN Cloud|<---------->|User Laptop (vpn connect)|
LAN 192.168.1.0/24
Device 1: 192.168.1.1
Device 2: 192.168.1.2
```

The problem here is the device that I am trying to access is a PLC and on this particular platform I need to specify the IP address rather than accessing it through a domain name. I was advised to use a different IP address for each device but the obvious downside to this solution is that the entire network becomes more and more difficult to manage as the number of device increases.

Is there a better way to deal with this type of situation? I think what I am trying to achieve is quiet common in industrial environment and I am wondering how people have dealt with the problem.

Comment: Usually this is done by using Network Address Translation. You’ll need to map all these devices on to a different address space that isn’t used everywhere. So, the remote devices don’t connect to 192.168.1.1. They’ll connect to 172.19.39.1 instead. Or something like that. Internally, the device IP addresses don’t change.

Comment: @Appleoddity thank you :) I am new to the world of networking and I my understanding of NAT is quiet limited so please do bear with me.. on my router (RUT240 from teltonika) I can define source zone, destination zone, and SNAT IP address. Would I be correct in saying that my source zone will be traffic from OpenVPN cloud and my destination zone will be LAN (192.168.1.0/24)? but I am a bit confused by this setup since all traffic will be mapped to a single IP address..?